# Is there a Calabi-Yau threefold with $h^{1,1}=1$ and $h^{1,2}=0$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, calabi-yau

Is there a Calabi-Yau threefold with $h^{1,1}=1$ and $h^{1,2}=0$?

Comment: As of three years ago no such CY threefold was known to the authors of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.06303.pdf.